# Egyptian multiplication algorithm complexity?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, multiplication

I do understand the algorithm but can't find a way to define its complexity, the only thing i know is it have something to with the second parameter, because if it was smaller the steps will be fewer. Do you have any idea how can i do this? and is there any general way to define time complexity for any given algorithm?

egyptian multiplication algorithm:

```
def egMul(x, y):
res = 0
while(y>0):
    if(y%2==0):
        x = x * 2
        y = y / 2
    else:
        y = y - 1
        res = res + x
return res
```

Comment: *"is there any general way to define time complexity for any given algorithm?"* The general idea is to count how many times the loops will execute. Which means you need to understand the condition(s) which causes the loop to terminate, and how the loop body modifies the loop variable(s). In other words, the analysis is specific to the code. There's no easy answer that applies to all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code performs Theta(log(y)) arithmetic operations. By considering the binary representation of  `y`, you can see it performs the `else` branch for each `1` that appears in the binary representation, and it performs the first branch of the `if` (the one that divides `y` by 2) `floor(log_2(y))` times.