# Understanding Worst Case Running Time without a pseudo-code algorithm (Egyptian Multiplication)

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I've been given a question by my professor in Data Structures and Algorithms, and I'm having a hard time understanding how I should be answering something like this. As I've already moved on to analyzing algorithms, to be asked a question outside of the context of a pseudo-code algorithm is really messing me up.

[In this video](https://youtu.be/HJ_PP5rqLg0?t=177), this individual goes over the concept of Egyptian Multiplication in which you multiply numbers from one to n on the left hand side until you have enough numbers to sum to your original number. On the other side, you double your original number equally in iterations to the left hand side until you, again, have the numbers necessary on the left hand side to sum to your original left-hand number. You then take the key-value pairs only where the keys add to the original number, and sum their values to find the answer to the original question: 9 x 13.

Since I am not seeing anything at face-value, I thought I'd try to code the first part, finding the key-value pairs to have something to look at.

In python, I came up with something like the following for finding the key-vaule pairs:

```
def egyptian_multiplication(a, b):
    result = 0
    right = 1
    left = b
    pairs = {}
    pairs[str(right)] = left
    while right < a:
        right = right * 2
        left = left * 2
        pairs[str(right)] = left
    print(pairs)

egyptian_multiplication(9, 13)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'1': 13, '2': 26, '4': 52, '8': 104, '16': 208}
```

Okay, so from what I can see, we're at O(n) complexity here. But now for the second part.

From a literal perspective, you need to traverse `pairs.keys()` as integers to find which combination adds to a, and subsequently add those associated values together. I have seen this solved in one place online not using packages that ended up being solved recursively.

The question, however, **isn't to write it out in psedo-code** and analyze it that way. The question is simply *what is the worse case running time for Egyptian Multiplication? What are the elementary steps to solve this problem?*

I'm completely thrown off by this because I'm not looking at code line by line. I need to define the elementary steps required to solve the algorithm, and then provide the worst case running time. Maybe I'm thinking too hard about this when I'm supposed to just *see* something at face value, but I'm not seeing it and I'm really trying my darnedest here to put this in terms that I can understand.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65055953/egyptian-multiplication-algorithm-complexity) stack overflow question that claims they're doing Egyptian Multiplication, but it is actually detailed in the video as *Russian Multiplication*, so I do not believe that solves my problem.

If anyone can help me, I really am trying to understand this on my own.

Comment: [Sometimes it's better just to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication). Even though Egyptian and Russian use slightly different methods, the time complexity is the same, and it's not O(n).

Comment: If writing out pseudocode helps you figure out the elementary steps, then writing out pseudocode is fine.  If the pseudocode corresponds one to one with the steps you actually perform, then the complexity will be the same.